# Fabric: How to listen to multiple channels in a single listener

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

My code is based on https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/off_chain_data/blockEventListener.js

The listener right now listens to only one single channel. I would like to enable it to listen to more than one channel.

My current code for adding listeners is as follows:

```
let network, listener
for (var i=0; i<channelid.length; i++) {
    let cid = channelid[i]
    console.log(`Adding listener for channel ${cid}`)
    network = await gateway.getNetwork(cid)
    listener = await network.addBlockListener(
        async (event) => {
            await ProcessingMap.set(event.blockData.header.number, event.blockData)
            console.log(`[${cid}] Added block ${event.blockData.header.number} to ProcessingMap`)
        },
        { startBlock: parseInt(nextBlock, 10) }
    )

    console.log(`[${cid}]: Listening for block events, nextblock: ${nextBlock}`)
    processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, cid)
};
```

And this is my code for `processPendingBlocks()`:

```
async function processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        let nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8")
        let processBlock

        do {
            processBlock = ProcessingMap.get(nextBlockNumber)
            if (processBlock == undefined) {
                break
            }

            try {
                await blockProcessing.processBlockEvent(channelid, processBlock, sdkAddress, sdkPort)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to process block: ${error}`)
            }

            ProcessingMap.remove(nextBlockNumber)
            fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(nextBlockNumber, 10) + 1)
            nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8")
        } while (true)

        processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid)
    }, 250)
}
```

This is my output:

```
[root@isprintdev nodejs]# node blockEventListener.js
Wallet path: /root/nodejs/wallet
Adding listener for channel dsprintchannel
[dsprintchannel]: Listening for block events, nextblock: 1

Adding listener for channel esprintchannel
[dsprintchannel] Added block 1 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 2 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 3 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 4 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 5 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 6 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 7 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 8 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 9 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 10 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 11 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 12 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 13 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 14 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 15 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 16 to ProcessingMap
[dsprintchannel] Added block 17 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel]: Listening for block events, nextblock: 1

[esprintchannel] Added block 1 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel] Added block 2 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel] Added block 3 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel] Added block 4 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel] Added block 5 to ProcessingMap
[esprintchannel] Added block 6 to ProcessingMap
------------------------------------------------
```

I see that the blocks from both channels are being added, but subsequent output shows that only those from the first channel (`dsprintchannel`) is being processed.

How should I change my code so that data from all channels are processed, instead of only those from the first channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that ProcessingMap is scoped outside of the loop where you are creating your listeners.  So basically you only have a single map so one channel will initially populate ProcessingMap[block_num] and then subsequent channels will simply set that same map entry again.  So I would move `let ProcessingMap = new BlockMap()` (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/off_chain_data/blockEventListener.js#L78) inside your `for (var i=0; i<channelid.length; i++) {...}` loop.